# How to control my application when it is open in two different tabs

Tags: javascript

Whenever I launch home page of my application, there is a drowdown present in header. So user, can select any value from that dropdown. And that value will be stored in localStorage.

The issue is, if user will open application in one more tab, and select any other value from dropdown other than the one selected in earlier window, then, new value of dropdown will be updated in localStorage. So, it can cause conflict in other operations.

So, my requirement is to check that if user opens another tab, and select some value from dropdown. Then in earlier tab he should get one alert saying that dropdown value has been changed.

Comment: Not claiming it's the best solution but you could listen for changes to localstorage `window.addEventListener('storage', ...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

```
// create new channel
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my-channel");
//send data
channel.postMessage("Hey, how's it going mate? I'm from a different tab!");
```

another tab:

```
// subscribe to the same channel, "my-channel"
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my-channel");

channel.addEventListener("message", e => {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

Or if you need support IE 11 and Safari, you can use `storage` event

```
window.addEvenLister('storage', ()=>{
   //this callback run every time when you did some changes in another tab with local storage
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage